# How much "compounded" asafoetida to use?

Tags: indian-cuisine, ingredient-selection, conversion

I have a UK-Indian recipe that calls for asafoetida (1/4 teaspoons). I have bought this:

[image]

This says it is "compounded" asafoetida powder. Is this any different from what would be used for my recipe? Do I use the amount called for, or less/more? The listed ingredients are gum arabic, wheat starch, and asafoetida.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Asafoetida is most commonly found in a "compounded" form.  It's about 30% asafoetida resin mixed with rice or wheat flour, and gum arabic.  Use it as your recipe directs.  It's fairly potent.  I use about 1/4 tsp at a time.

Comment: It's also available mixed with fenugreek, again at 30%. I like the flavour and batch cook, using up to nearly a teaspoon in 4-6 portions. You should need a little less of this type